# Pass query parameters to Flask decorator

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm setting up a token auth system for my Flask server, and I want to be able to setup a decorator to look something like this:

```
@app.route('/my/data/')
@requires_token_auth
def get_my_endpoint_data():
    """Return JSON data""""
    return get_data()
```

Then I'll hit the endpoint like /my/data?token=myawesometokenvalue

I've setup my decorator function like

```
def requires_token_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        ... do stuff ...
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
return wrapped
```

Unfortunately, the 'token' parameter is not made available inside of args. The problem seems to be that Flask passes the req.view_args through, instead of req.args.

*** From flask's app.py ***

```
1344         return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
```

How can I access query parameters from inside of a wrapped function?

Comment: Where's your code that tries to access the `token` parameter?

Comment: Inside the wrapped decorator function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is the first google result for "flask query parameters decorator", this is the solution I ended up with to add the query parameters, on top of path parameters in methods:

```
def query_params(f):
    """
    Decorator that will read the query parameters for the request.
    The names are the names that are mapped in the function.
    """
    parameter_names = inspect.getargspec(f).args

    @wraps(f)
    def logic(*args, **kw):
        params = dict(kw)

        for parameter_name in parameter_names:
            if parameter_name in request.args:
                params[parameter_name] = request.args.get(parameter_name)

        return f(**params)

    return logic

@app.route('/hello/<uid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@query_params
def hello_world(uid, name):
    return jsonify({
        'uid': uid,
        'name': name
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I just realized that I can do it the same way as I normally would!

```
token = request.args.get('token')
```