# Flask: pass url path to class constructor

Tags: python, flask

I am trying something probably highly unorthodox: I need to pass an argument, that comes in via the url path to the class constructor of a class-based MethodView.

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/child/my_id_string
```

I want to pass `my_id_string` to the following constructor as `arg1`.

My most promissing try was based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456678/pass-query-parameters-to-flask-decorator), but I need to use class-based views instead of functions. Unfortunately the logic behind this call is somewhat more complex than the example, i.e I cannot simply refactor the code to not use "my_id" in the constructor.

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.views import MethodView

BASE = 11
app = Flask('mybase')

class Child(MethodView):
    def __init__(self, base, arg1=None):
        self.base = base
        print('some init process, where I need arg1...')

    def get(self, arg1):
        return f'Some operation with {str(arg1)}.'

app.add_url_rule(
    '/child/<arg1>',
    'child',
    view_func=Child.as_view(
        'child_view',
        BASE,
        arg1 = request.args.get('my_id')
    ),
    methods=['GET',]
)
```

I get the following error with the snippet as is, because I figure the registration occurs before/without a specific request, is that correct?
Hope, someone is able to help. Thanks in advance!

> RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
> an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
> information about how to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused about your syntax of :
`app = flask("mybase")` :i use `app = flask(__name__)`

But this is what i would do.

```
@app.route("/child/<arg1>")
def x(arg1):
   varArg1 = arg1
   #now you have whatever is in the url will be passed into varArg1.
```

Comment: Thanks. That is admittedly not really the solution to my problem, but I figured something out in the meantime. Regarding your first comment/confiusion see [Flask API](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question.  My solution looked like this:

```py
@api.doc("""Return a report by method name""")
@api.route("/reports/<method_name>")
class ReportByMethod(Reporter):
    def __init__(self, method_name):
        self.method_name = method_name
        super().__init__()

    def get(self, method_name):
        return ['method_name']
```

As far as my (limited) testing goes the <method_name> is passed both to the constructor and to the ReportByMethod.get() function.